# Badge progress for all badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

Is there a way to see the progress for the all badges available? For example i want to know when i will get a "Popular Question" badge - so i need to explore all my questions and take a look at all views.

Just like this but for all badges:

[image]

Comment: Excellent question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This doesn't make sense for *all* badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/168293#168293).

You never go backwards in your progress toward the examples that do show progress - that makes showing progress a very good motivator. You can also see your progress toward Fanatic by visiting your profile, although that one you *can* go backwards on if you miss a day (and as a result folks tend to get rather... upset... now and then when their day doesn't align with UTC, or they get sick or something).

There'll probably be more progress indicators added eventually - indeed, [we just redesigned the badges page to better indicate progress when one badge is itself a milemarker of sorts toward another](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges) - but requiring this for *all* badges limits the sort of criteria that can be set for badges.